# Flutter Reset BlockPicker

Tags: flutter, picker, color-picker

I want to reset this Blockpicker/Colorpicker: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_colorpicker after I already picked one. Any ideas?

Then it does not have to be a selected color.

I thought to use the `SetState` but it change nothing.

That's the widget. I modified it:

```dart
class _DayButtonState extends State<DayButton> {
  late Color pickedColor = widget.initColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>    return TextButton( //<-- TextButton included
      child: Text(""),
      onPressed: () {},
      onLongPress: () async {
>        Navigator.push( //<-- Navigator included
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text(''),
              ),
              body: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 400,
                    width: 400,
                    child: BlockPicker(
                      pickerColor: pickedColor,
                      layoutBuilder: (context, colors, child) {
                        return GridView.builder(
                          itemCount: colors.length,
                          gridDelegate:
                              const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 4,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 12,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 12,
                          ),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Material(
                              color: colors[index],
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    pickedColor = colors[index];
                                  });
                                },
                                child: pickedColor == colors[index]
                                    ? Icon(Icons.check)
                                    : null,
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      onColorChanged: (Color color) {
                        pickedColor = widget.initColor;
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  RawMaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      pickedColor = widget.initColor;
                      widget.changeColor("", pickedColor);
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    child: Text("reset"),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          }),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

But if I add Textbutton and Navigator it doesn't work anymore.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include what you;ve tried so far?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh: I hope that helps to understand. I edit it.

Comment: Can you include full widget

Answer (score 0):

The  `BlockPicker` doesnt update ui inside its state class and callback method just provide the color.

We can use `layoutBuilder` from `BlockPicker`. I've modify the structure, decorate the way you like.

```dart
class DayButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color initColor;
  final void Function(Color) changeColor;

  const DayButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.initColor,
    required this.changeColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DayButton> createState() => _DayButtonState();
}

class _DayButtonState extends State<DayButton> {
  late Color pickedColor = widget.initColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 400,
          width: 400,
          child: BlockPicker(
            pickerColor: pickedColor,
            layoutBuilder: (context, colors, child) {
              return GridView.builder(
                itemCount: colors.length,
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 4,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 12,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 12,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Material(
                    color: colors[index],
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          pickedColor = colors[index];
                        });
                      },
                      child: pickedColor == colors[index]
                          ? Icon(Icons.check)
                          : null,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
            onColorChanged: (Color color) {
              pickedColor = widget.initColor;
              setState(() {});
            },
          ),
        ),
        RawMaterialButton(
          onPressed: () {
            pickedColor = widget.initColor;
            widget.changeColor(pickedColor);
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: Text("reset"),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And using like

```dart
DayButton(
  changeColor: (p0) {
    print("$p0  ");
    setState(() {});
  },
  initColor: Colors.green,
),
```

Comment: I tried your solution. It works but if I add TextButton and Navigation it doesn't. I can't figure out why.
I moved also `late Color pickedColor = widget.initColor;` over `return Scaffold` but it didn't work out

Comment: once you do `Navigation` means it is on different route